# Adding Multiple Network Printers

Tags: printing

I have to setup laptops for about 20 distribution offices (one laptop per office). Each office has (2) printers (Konica Minolta and HP).

So that the user can choose either printer, where is the printer information stored?

Are there instructions on how to do this?

Comment: eh where is the server that holds the printers? Is that a windows machine? an Ubuntu desktop with cups? Or something else? The latter: you can see the printers from the browser: http://localhost:631 But... printers should be accessible on the fly.

Comment: The printers are stand alone network printers. There is no print server. Each laptop  runs Ubuntu. I can only see one printer rather be able to choose one or the other. I  think the information I was looking for is in the printers.conf...checking that now

Answer (score 0):

The information is stored in `/etc/cups/printers.conf` and you can use `http://localhost:631` to set it up.

If you're going to copy the configuration between machines, watch out that you also need to copy the directory `/etc/cups/ppd/` and possibly copy the drivers themselves (e.g. for Brother printers that's in /opt/brother), unless they're shipped as part of CUPS.

Comment: Thanks Dave, that's the information I was looking for

Comment: Good. You could click on the "up arrow" symbol ("this information is useful") then, or even accept the answer (there must be a button or link for that somewhere).